# Textarea strange behavior inside a form

Tags: javascript, html

My issue is quite simple.
I am not able to put new lines / press enter to put a new line inside if the textarea is inside a form.

Works great outside the form. **I NEED the form and I cannot remove it. The textarea must be inside the form**

Is there a way to fix this? Why this happens?

```
<form>
   <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: form elements can be submitted by pressing enter, that's its default behavior

Comment: @AngelSalazar While a textarea-element has focus, it normally handles the enter-key so the user can add several lines without the form being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information, it just works that way, I think you should share the CSS applied on both elements.

Make sure the text area is focused when pressing Enter otherwise it should submit

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example. In my browser (Chome) I can press enter while inside the text-area, without the form being submitted. Does that work for you too? Then there is something else with your code that causes the form to be submitted.

```js
myForm.addEventListener("submit",event=>{
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Form submit", Date.now());
});
```

```css
input[type=text],
textarea{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <textarea>Enter you text here. You should be able to press enter here to create a new line, without the form being submitted.</textarea><br>
  <input type="text" value="Pressing enter here will submit the form"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I will try this

Comment: @TiagoSilva You can try it by clicking "run code snippet" here on stackoverflow. While you are inside the textarea you should be able to press enter without the form being submitted, but if you are in the input-field or press the submit-button the form will be submitted ( and it will be logged to the screen )

Comment: Did not work. When I press enter it still does not allow to new line

Comment: Then there is something strange with your  browser. I tested it with Chrome and Firefox. What browser are you using? Any plugins?